# Access module web/images from module's block and display?

Tags: magento2, php

I have tried this which gives me the images url for my theme, which does not have the images that are located in my module/view/frontend/web/images folder.

```
return $this->getViewFileUrl($image_path);
```

Where do static images go inside a module, and how can they be used in a block?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to change the destination of your images and then you would be able to fetch static images

1. Put your image on Your Magento 2 Path: /app/design/frontend///web/images
2. Use this code to call the image in phtml file

```
<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/demo.jpg'); ?>
```

Comment: That is what I'm doing now, however it doesn't seem like best practise. Why should a module's images and display depend upon the theme?

Comment: Vendor_Module::...?

Comment: are you asking that the image is in the Vendor module ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking.